# Java : Read a file with special characters from a Zip file

Tags: java, character-encoding, zip

I have a zip file with the following content:

[image]

The content inside *Temperature_°C.log* : **unit°C**

and i use the following code to print all the file names inside a zip:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("Test.zip", Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

            Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = zipFile.entries();
            while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
                try {
                    ZipEntry zipEntry = entries.nextElement();
                    System.out.println(zipEntry.getName());

                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            zipFile.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ZipTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

and at line : `ZipEntry zipEntry = entries.nextElement();` for the **Temperature_°C.log** it throws `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: MALFORMED`

I tried `UTF-8` and it is not working. When i tried with `ISO-8859-1` it displays junk character.

How should i solve this ?

Comment: Is the displayed junk character `ø` _Latin Small Letter O With Stroke_? It's mojibake with `cp437` (or whatever is OEM code page on computer where the zip file was created).

Comment: @JosefZ When using Commons-compress , i get *Temperature_øC.log* for normal java i get a square.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the same problem, but with cyrillic characters. Had to use [commons-compress](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/index.html) library instead of standard.

```java
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipArchiveEntry;
import org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.ZipFile;


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try(ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile("Test.zip")) { //UTF-8 by default
        Enumeration<ZipArchiveEntry> entries = zipFile.getEntries();
        while (entries.hasMoreElements()) {
            try {
                ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry = entries.nextElement();
                System.out.println(zipEntry.getName());
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(ZipTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! With Compress i get the following for "ISO-8859-1"  *Temperature_øC.log* and "UTF-8" its *Temperature_?C.log* . Encoding is wrong ?

Comment: Hmm... Tried creating archive with Total Commander using Zip packer setting "Pack Unicode names"="All as UTF-8 if at least one contains characters>127" (since dergee sign is 176) and it worked both with commons-compress and with std!